# Geometric progression — Sum of terms, sum of terms' cubes, sum of terms' squares

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the infinite geometric progression $a_1, a_2, a_3, \dots$. Given the sum of its terms, as well as the sum of the terms' cubes

$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots = 3\\
a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 + \cdots = \frac{108}{13}$

find the sum of the terms' squares

$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + \cdots$

---

This is what I have so far:

$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + \cdots = 3\\
\Longrightarrow 1 + q + q^2 + \cdots = \frac{3}{a_1}$

$a_1^3 + a_2^3 + a_3^3 + \cdots = \frac{108}{13}\\
\Longrightarrow 1 + q^3 + q^6 + \cdots = \frac{108}{13a_1}$

$a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2 + \cdots\\
= \frac{a_1^3}{a_1} + \frac{a_2^3}{a_2} + \frac{a_3^3}{a_3} + \cdots\\
= \frac{a_1^3}{a_1} \left(1 + \frac{q^3}{q} + \frac{q^6}{q^2} + \cdots\right)$

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let the first term be $a$ and the common ratio be $r$

For [convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence) we need $|r|<1$

So, the sum of the first series $\sum_{0\le n<\infty}a\cdot r^n=\frac a{1-r}=3\ \ \  \  (1)$

So, the sum of the second  series $\sum_{0\le n<\infty}a^3\cdot (r^3)^n=\frac {a^3}{1-r^3}=\frac{108}{13}\ \ \  \ (2) $

Cube the first & divide by $(2)$ to get $r$ and then get $a$ from $(1)$

We need $$\sum_{0\le n<\infty}a^2\cdot (r^2)^n=\frac{a^2}{1-r^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $a_n=ar^{n-1}$, then $a_n^2=a^2(r^2)^{n-1}$ and $a_n^3=a^3(r^3)^{n-1}$.

Each of these is a geometric series; and we have assumed that they all converge.

In fact, we know that
$$\tag{1}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ar^{n-1}=3\qquad\text{and}\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^3(r^3)^{n-1}=\frac{108}{13}.
$$

But we also know how to sum geometric series in general:
$$\tag{2}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ar^{n-1}=\frac{a}{1-r}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^3(r^3)^{n-1}=\frac{a^3}{1-r^3}.
$$
What can you determine about $a$ and $r$ from the combination of (1) and (2)?