# Geometric Series TMUA exam question. Where did I go wrong.

Tags: summation, geometric-series

> The sum to infinity of a geometric progression is 6.
>   The sum to infinity of the squares of each term in the progression is 12.
>   Find the sum to infinity of the cubes of each term in the progression.
>   A 8
>   B 18
>   C 24
>   D 216/7
>   E 72
>   F 216

Lets say a = first term and r = common ratio. 
I understand how the mark scheme derived their answer but I am unsure as to what I did incorrect in my calculation.

So I got:

$$\frac{a}{1-r} = 6$$ and $$\frac{a}{1-r^2} = 12$$

$6(1-r) = 12(1-r^2)$

$12r^2 - 6r - 6 = 0$

$2r^2 - r - 1 = 0$

$(2r + 1)(r - 1) = 0$
because |r| < 1
$$\therefore r = -1/2$$
so $a = 6 - 6(\frac{-1}{2})$

$$a = 9$$

The sum to infinity of cubes of each term: $$\frac{a}{1-r^3}$$

$$\frac{9}{1 - (\frac {-1}{2})^3} = \frac {9}{1 + (\frac{1}{8})} = 8$$

However the answer is 216/7. I am unsure as to where I went wrong in my calculation. I am guessing I shouldn't have multiplied out to get $a = 12(1 - r^2)$ because r could take two values? One being the correct value and the other being the opposite sign of the correct value?

Comment: Always try to write down the first few terms...Also see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443533/geometric-progression-sum-of-terms-sum-of-terms-cubes-sum-of-terms-squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original series is $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots$ and its sum is indeed $\frac a{1-r}$. But the series of the squares is $a^2+a^2r^2+a^2r^4+a^2r^6+\cdots$ and its sum is $\frac{a^2}{1-r^2}$.

Comment: A little overlook gave a completely different answer. I will look out for things like this next time. Thanks!